# Mapbox gl - Custom filter and render of PBF tiles

Tags: mapbox-gl-js

```
map.addSource('testLayer', {
    'type': 'vector',
    'source-layer': 'testLayer',
    'tiles': [
        'http://localhost:3004/{z}/{x}/{y}.pbf'
    ],
    'minzoom': 0,
    'maxzoom': 24,
});
map.addLayer({
    'id': 'urban-areas-fill',
    'source': 'testLayer',
    // Custom styling based on filtering. Help needed here
});
```

Above pbf tile contains point data, along with height attribute. I want to collect height attribute of all the points within each tile, take an average of it per tile, use it for each individual point's height value (respective to that tile) to perform certain filtering (if else) and assign colours accordingly to display. Also, I want to convert the final rendering of each point as pixel (ie rectangle), and not as a circle. Thanks :)

Comment: What is your question? You've just stated a series of goals.

Comment: add source sourcelayername